# Catch mouseover and onclick for elements with different z indices

Tags: javascript, onclick, copy, onmouseover, zeroclipboard

I want to make a webpage that allows a user to select and copy an HTML entity with a single click, and using ZeroClipboard should be good enough for this.  I want to have tens, maybe even hundreds of copyable HTML entities on the page, so I would prefer not to have a ZeroClipboard client for each entity.  The solution I came up with is to have a table of HTML entities where each td contains a different HTLM entity, and captures onmouseover, so I can determine which HTML entity the user wants.  Then I glue the ZeroClipboard to this table to capture the onclick.  By default the ZeroClipboard object has z-index 99 so it sits over the table.  Unfortunately since the ZeroClipboard object has nothing to do with the table semantically the events can't propagate to the td which is hidden underneath.

Is there a way to capture the onclick on the ZeroClipboard object (embed) with a z-index of 99, and also capture the onmouseover on the td that sits underneath with a z-index of 1?  Do I need to find the coordinates of the mouse cursor to do this?  I would rather not do that because a) it's messy and b) technically impossible with the W3C specifications.

I've frozen two copies of my current code:

ZeroClipboard embed z-index=99 : http://www.aidansean.com/physics/symbols_static.php 
(This can copy the "..." contents of the box in the upper left.)

ZeroClipboard embed z-index=-99: http://www.aidansean.com/physics/symbols_static_2.php
(This can change the "..." contents of the box in the upper left.)

I want to combine the functionality of both of these pages.  Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hey. I don't see yet the differences between the two, nor do I clearly understand what you actually do want.
What should the functionality be, and what is currently not working as required? Apologies if I have misread your post :-) I do believe that it is easy to put a mouseover to underlying element(s), with an onclick for elements within/with a higher z-index. Also, I noticed that the inline style is changed on mouseover, whilst it would be neater to toggle classnames :-) Or even better: .td_symbol:hover { border-style: dashed; }

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the reply!  Apologies about the same behaviour- I linked to the same js file in both by mistake.  What I want to to do is place an embed over the top of a td element (but not inside it).  Then when the user moves over a symbol and clicks, the embed captures the onclick event and copies a string to the clipboard.  This is easy enough- the embed gets placed over the table using absolute positioning and z-index=99.  But then the td underneath cannot capture onmouseover, so it can't update the text that needs to be copied.  I think what I want to do is actually impossible. :(

Comment: Please do update that in your post (so it becomes instantly clear what your goal is). Perhaps you could use two 'embeds' (as you name them). One is the fake one that the user does see (highest z-index), and the other one is UNDER the TD (unseen), that will capture the click. Plausible?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, there you go. Some other options I tried, didn't work. Is this a helpful solution? :)

[JSFiddle: Click at embedded with lower z-index](http://jsfiddle.net/hpRZE/65/)

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks again!  Unfortunately while this captures the Javascript events it will not work for the purpose I want, which is using ZeroClipboard, because that must always be on top.  However, you've inspired another solution which I'm currently working on.  This new solution sets the z-index for all tds to 3, and the z-index for the ZeroClipboard embed to 2.  Then when the user hovers over a td, its z-index changes to 1 (so it's below the embed) and updates the characters to be updated, ready to be copied to the clipboard when the user clicks.  Thanks again!

Comment: Right on, good luck ;) :D Perhaps you would want to mark this as helpful or post your own solution, if people come across the same issue ;-)